# Submit form after click

Tags: php, jquery

Having Following form validation through jQuery:

```
$("#Login").submit(function( event ) {
    var url = 'ajax/';
    var data = {};
    $("input").each(function() {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); 
    });
    $.post(url,data,function( resp ) {
        $("#formLoginErrorMessage").children().remove();
        if(resp === " ")
        {                
            console.log("Empty");
            return; // The form should submit
        } else if (typeof resp === "object") {
            console.log(resp);
        } else{
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").append("<li>" + resp + "</li>");
            console.log(resp);
        }
    },'json');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This script is checking some **errors** and when *resp* is empty form should submit. But **return** from *if* where **resp** is checked doesn't seem to make form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) method in the `if` condition

```
$("#Login").submit(function (event) {
    var form = this;
    var url = 'ajax/';
    var data = {};
    $('input').each(function () {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    $.post(url, data, function (resp) {
        $("#formLoginErrorMessage").children().remove();
        if (resp === " ") {
            form.submit();
            console.log("Empty");
            return; // The form should submit
        } else if (typeof resp === "object") {
            console.log(resp);
        } else {
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").append("<li>" + resp + "</li>");
            console.log(resp);
        }
    }, 'json');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: change **this.submit();** to **form.submit();** and it will work.

Comment: and remove **return;** it's not necessary there. Thanks to @php_nub_qq

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be confused about are closures

```
$( "#Login" ).submit(function( event ) {

   // main submit handling function starts here

   ...

   $.post(url,data,function(resp){

       // inner response handling function starts here

        if(resp === " "){               
               console.log("Empty");
               return; //This returns to jQuery internals somewhere inside $.post
        } ...
    },'json');

    // stops form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I added a couple of comments to help you get a better visual of the scope.

First thing first, you should never rely on client-side validation. It can be overtaken without exceptions. If for some reason you insist on having it this way you can use some outer scope variable to determine whether validation has passed or not, but then you have to use `$form.submit()` instead of `return` to actually submit the form.